# Changing the text (updating the site) in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I **update** my WordPress site; The site will be temporarily unavailable to users and a text will be displayed stating that the site has been updated.

I am looking for a code so that I can change the display **text** and also display an **image** to the user.

I don't know any code or solution for this issue and I searched for such code but didn't find anything.

I need any kind of help or guidance.

Thank you in advance.